# Unexpected behavior of indexed for loop

Tags: java, android, loops, java-8, nested-loops

I'm learning Android development, and I have encountered a problem:
I have an activity with a button; when the button is pressed, it executes this:

```java
   for (int j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 256 ; k++) {
              MainActivity.infolog("X="+j+" Y="+k);
         }
   }
```

*infolog* is a shortcut for `Log.i(LOG_TAG,object.toString())`.
Initially, the values reported are correct:

```
    X=1 Y=181
    X=1 Y=182
    X=1 Y=183
    X=1 Y=184
    X=1 Y=185
    X=1 Y=186
    X=1 Y=187
    X=1 Y=188
    X=1 Y=189
    X=1 Y=190
    X=1 Y=191
```

Then some of the values of both variables are being skipped:

```
    X=34 Y=108
    X=34 Y=109
    X=34 Y=114
    X=34 Y=115
    X=34 Y=118
    X=34 Y=120
    X=34 Y=121
    X=34 Y=127
```

I'm running this app on my mobile phone via USB; SDK versions - 19-28.

Comment: Why do you need such log statements? For loop is working correctly sometimes logging the statement takes time

Comment: There may simply be too much output to LogCat, or it's determining the information is meaningless is skipping it. You could try writing your results to somewhere else instead, like a file, and reading from there.

Comment: Do one thing, keep appending the output to StringBuilder/StringBuffer and when for loop is over, print StringBuilder/StringBuffer toString() output to log

Comment: @RahulKhurana My app is going to deal with transforming Bitmaps, so I thought that using the logger will help me check the pixel data using for-loop. That's why I tried that on a smaller scale. Knowing that the logger can skip statement helps.